# Function to calculate absolute value of given numbers

Tags: function, arduino, calculation

complete newbie here. I need help making two functions abs1 and abs2, in order to calculate the absolute value of the numbers -2 and -7, and print them out so it displays 27. However i don't want to change the existing loop i made, i want to add the functions separately. This is being coded on an Arduino.

This is the code i have written so far:

```c
void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600)

}

void loop() {

    int number1 = -2;

    int number2 = -7;

    number1 = abs1(number1);

    abs2(&number2);

    Serial.print(number1);

    Serial.print(number2); 

}
```

I have tried to use `int abs1=abs(number1)`, but it only gives the error messages"number1 was not declared" or "abs1 was not declared" or " Failed to compile for Arduino Genuino Mega 2560" depending on where I place the line.

Comment: `int abs1=abs(number1)` should work.  According to the error, it looks like you forgot  the declare `number1` the way you did in the code block.  Make sure you included that line: `int number1 = -2;`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need two functions?  Why not use the regular old abs function?

```
void loop() {

int number1 = -2;

int number2 = -7;

number1 = abs(number1);

number2 = abs(number2);

Serial.print(number1);

Serial.print(number2);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to print the absolute values just use the abs function at serial print.

```
void loop() {

int number1 = -2;

int number2 = -7;

Serial.print(abs(number1));

Serial.print(abs(number2)); 
}
```